# Sheets that have almost the same name

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to open and copy the cells from a sheet from a different excel file. I have no problem in opening, copying and closing the excel file that I need.In this case, I have `With x.Sheets("Documents").UsedRange`. Most files that I needed to copy the cells from have "Documents" as a sheet name, but some have "Documents" + other different characters (example, "DocuemntsEX"). When I tried to copy, it shows 'Subscript Out-of-range' since the "DocumentEX" is different from "Document". Is there any way that I can retain the specific name of the sheet, since most of the files have that name? Is there any code that can help me to access those sheet with a different sheetname? Just hit me up if you need clarifications.

Comment: if sheets are on same index, you can use `Sheets("sheetNumber")` (without "", so e.g Sheets(2)

Comment: `Just hit me up if you need clarifications.` absolutely 100% need clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a wildcard character to get the sheet first:

```
Function GetDocumentSheet(ByRef wb As Workbook) As Worksheet

    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        If LCase$(ws.Name) Like "documents*" Then
            Set GetDocumentSheet = ws
            GoTo SheetFound:
        End If
    Next

    Set GetDocumentSheet = Nothing

SheetFound:    
End Function
```

In your code:

```
Set mySheet = GetDocumentSheet(x) '// where 'x' is your workbook object
```

Then reference

```
mySheet.UsedRange
```

Comment: will be better to remove casecensitivity using `Lcase` or `Ucase`, or `option compare text`, e.g. `Lcase(ws.Name) Like "documents*"`, otherwise might be some problems

Answer (score 0):

As i said in comment, you can use sheets by number, or you can use something like this

```
Sub findSheet()

Dim sheetSubName As String
sheetSubName = "fluff"

Dim currentSheet As Worksheet

For Each currentSheet In Sheets

    If currentSheet.Name Like sheetSubName & "*" Then
        MsgBox "do some stuff"
    End If

Next currentSheet

End Sub
```

When you comparing sheet name to string and regular character (in my example * so its anything). So this macro will work with sheet fluff, fluffy fluffiest etc.

And everything to looping via `Sheets` (all sheet in workbook) and comparing their names via `Like` (something like = ) but it can use some basic regular expression.